# center_horizontal="true" не работает в CardView

Tags: android, xml, cardview

Этот `layout` является элементом `RecyclerView`, главным слоем является `CardView`, но почему-то `center_horizontal="true"` не работает.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="23dp"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

    <!-- content -->

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если сделать так например:

```
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="23dp"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="12345"/>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

то будет так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а дальше если что можно убрать `center_vertical` и оно будет отцентрировано.

### UPDATE

Попробуйте у recyclerview установить layout_gravity = center

Comment: Оно меняется лишь на панельке отображения в Android Studio. На эмуляторе ни `center_vertical` ни `center_horizontal` не работают.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что `CardView` является лишь элементом `RecyclerView`. В следствии чего помогло увеличение `padding'a` у `RecyclerView`.

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:overScrollMode="never" />
```

Comment: то есть вы падингом отцентировали так как вам нужно?

Comment: По сути да, я сузил `RecyclerView`, в котором и расположен этот `CardView`

Comment: ну я ни в коем случае не критикую ваше решение, но вам не кажется что это немного костыль?) по логике можно gravity как-то регулировать)

Comment: обновил ответ с другим вариантом, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Посмотрел. Так в принципе тоже можно, но тогда уж лучше с `center_horizontal` только. Да и опять же у `RecyclerView` можно установить ширину меньше. Наверное так даже лучше.